# Integer в TDate

Tags: delphi

Пользуюсь компонентом `TChart`, для вывода по оси «*Х*», нужно отложить даты.
Я воспользовался:

```
Form1.Series1.AddXY(
  Trunc(DateOf(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('DATE_CONTROL').AsDateTime)), 
  L_DotAxisY,
  FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yy', ibqEmpty.FieldByName('DATE_CONTROL').AsDateTime)
    +','+#13#10+ ibqEmpty.FieldByName('DEPOSIT_ID').AsString,
  LColorLine
);
```

И по оси «*Х*», теперь откладываются целые числа.
Как их перевести назад в дату? (TDate) (когда я щелкаю на участок отрезка, я хочу выводить дату в hint, а не целое число).

Comment: - убрать `trunc`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы на оси чарта выводилась дата, а не число, нужно, чтобы на чарт выводилась хотя бы одна серия, у которой в свойствах оси указано `DateTime = True`

Для Вашего кода это будет выглядеть так

```
Form1.Series1.XValues.DateTime := True;
```

Если `Series1` у Вас создается в Design-Time, то ничто Вам не мешает это свойство выставить при настройке графика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]